# unable to run simple jenkins docker node build (home directories outside of /home are not currently supported)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, snapcraft

I am using a very simple script mentioned below as per the official docs (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:14-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simple as it is, it outputs follows:

```
22:58:45  [Pipeline] }
22:58:45  [Pipeline] // stage
22:58:45  [Pipeline] withEnv
22:58:45  [Pipeline] {
22:58:45  [Pipeline] isUnix
22:58:45  [Pipeline] sh
22:58:45  + docker inspect -f . node:14-alpine
22:58:46  Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. 
22:58:46  See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
22:58:46  [Pipeline] isUnix
22:58:46  [Pipeline] sh
22:58:46  + docker pull node:14-alpine
22:58:46  Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. 
22:58:46  See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
22:58:46  [Pipeline] }
22:58:46  [Pipeline] // withEnv
22:58:46  [Pipeline] }
22:58:46  [Pipeline] // node
22:58:46  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
22:58:46  ERROR: script returned exit code 1
22:58:46  Finished: FAILURE
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The hyperlink inside the message leads to a page that says:

> Snapd does currently not support running snaps if the home directory of the user is outside of /home.

It says that for the `docker` command.  I suspect you're trying to run the `docker` command as the `jenkins` user.  The default home directory for the `jenkins` user is `/var/lib/jenkins`.  The default home directory of the `jenkins` user is outside `/home`.

If that's the case, there are several alternatives available:

- Create a user on that computer with a home directory in `/home` and run a Jenkins agent as that user
- Install docker on that computer using `apt` instead of using `snapd` (following the Docker directions rather than the Ubuntu directions)
- Create a user on another computer with a home directory in `/home` and install docker there with `snapd`, then configure an agent to use that computer

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are inheriting the HOME environment variable from Jenkins in some way.  You can use env config to override that.  If you want the HOME from the worker node executing the docker build you can mount env.HOME into /home/jenkins (or something like that) into the container.

Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:14-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME:/home/jenkins'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: One thing that can be useful is to print the environment in a stage.  Switch it so the docker agent is only used in 'Test' step.  Then add a step before that that uses the a non docker agent and add something like: sh 'env' 

That will print the environment and you can see what HOME is set to